# Função recebe como parâmetro um vetor de strings

Tags: c, funções, parâmetros, char

Comecei à pouco tempo a aprender a linguagem de programação C e estou com dificuldades.

Declaro um vetor de strings, passo valores para esse vetor e de seguida passo esse mesmo vetor como argumento de uma função. O problema é aqui, quando corro o programa e no momento em que passo o vetor de strings como argumento, ele simplesmente deixa de funcionar.

Deixo aqui um exemplo de código, para verem como estou a fazer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void MostraTodos(char memoria[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char memoria[3][30];
    int i;
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("Introduza o seu nome\n");
    scanf("%s", &memoria[i]);
    }

MostraTodos(memoria);
return 0;
}


void MostraTodos(char memoria[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("%s", memoria[i]);
    }

}
```

Já pesquisei bastante e não encontro a resposta, ainda por cima penso que seja fácil de resolver.

Comment: Use assim: scanf_s("%s", &memoria[i], 30);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos motivos do erro é achar que existem *strings* em C. Na verdade existe *array* de `char` terminado com um nulo. Se conceituar isso corretamente fica mais fácil entender. Então tem dois erros, na verdade, o mesmo em dois lugares.

Um deles é que está parametrizando a função para receber um vetor de `char`, mas o que deseja é um vetor de vetores de 30 `char`s. Então isso é o que tem que usar no parâmetro.

O outro erro é que está passando para o `scanf()` um ponteiro o elemento do vetor quando deseja passar um ponteiro para o endereço onde começa o vetor de `char` de cada elemento, portanto tem que passar o elemento 0 deste vetor.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void MostraTodos(char memoria[][30]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) printf("%s\n", memoria[i]);
}

int main() {
    char memoria[3][30];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Introduza o seu nome\n");
        scanf("%s", &memoria[i][0]);
    }
    MostraTodos(memoria);
}
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KGm5a6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vevqxuyi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Array.c).

Comment: Antes de mais, obrigado pela sua resposta. Acho que percebi o que disse. No entanto fiquei com uma duvida: Das duas alterações que sugeriu, se eu só efetuar a primeira (char memoria[][30]) o programa, aparentemente, funciona corretamente sem dar algum tipo de erro. Poderia-me explicar o porquê de isto acontecer? Obrigado.

Comment: @Peixoto funciona em alguns compiladores. É o que eu sempre digo, funcionar é diferente de estar certo. o que funciona um dia pode deixar de funcionar, o certo é sempre certo. Por isso uma dos maiores aprendizados que um programador tem que ter é que não pode confiar no que funciona, tem que ter certeza que está certo. E para isto precisa de muita dedicação e estudo. Não pode fazer "nas coxas".